Looking for the most Pythonic way to change a list of booleans to an integer, turning them into a base 2 number, but I have a little extra logic too
So I'm working on a custom tiling method for a video game. I have the data of the types of local tiles stored as a list with True for the same type, and False for a different type, the tiles are laid out as follows:
| 7 | 0 | 1 |
-------------
| 6 |   | 2 |
-------------
| 5 | 4 | 3 |


Now there are a few (48 to be exact) distinct tile representations, however when I convert the boolean list to binary I get a number in (0,255). So obviously there are duplicates in the list so here's what removes those. The even numbers are the cardinal directions, they always represent themselves, the odd numbers however, should only populate if both neighboring cardinal directions are occupied (True).
| T | T | F |
-------------
| F |   | T |
-------------
| T | F | T |

output should be => [T,F,T,X,F,X,F,X] => 10100000 => 160

The X's could be anything, I'm probably going to go with 0.
So here's what I have tried:
#inputs
i,j = 1,1
pixels = [[True,False,True],[True,True,False],[False,True,True]]

#inside a function
binary_list = []
for x in [1,-1]:
    binary_list.append(pixels[i+0][i-x])
    for y in [-x,0,x]:
        binary_list.append(pixels[i+x][i+y]
binary_list.append(binary_list[-1])
str_bits = ""
for i in range(8):
    if not i % 2:
        str_bits = str_bits + str(int(binary_list[i]))
    elif binary_list[i-1] and binary_list[i+1]:
        str_bits = str_bits + str(int(binary_list[i]))
    else:
        str_bits = str_bits + "0"
#return value just return the int but for visibility now...
print(str_bits, int(str_bits, base=2))


So practically speaking I will be using a type_check instead of the pixels list reference, and yeah it works but how can I do it better/more pythonically?

When you're working with numbers, it's better to use integers instead of building a string and converting at the end.  Simple bit shifting does the same thing as appending digits to a string.
bin_bits = 0
for i in range(8):
    bin_bits <<= 1
    if not i % 2:
        bin_bits += binary_list[i]
    elif binary_list[i-1] and binary_list[i+1]:
        bin_bits += binary_list[i]
    else:
        pass # no need to append zeros


woah, very cool, didn't know about the "bitshift-equals" operation, thanks for the advice!
